# Counterexample of universal property of localization

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, localization

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with $1\not =0$, and let $D\ni 1$ be a multiplicative subset of $R$. Consider the universal characterization of $D^{-1}R$:

Universal property of localization is well known.

> There is a morphism $\pi\colon R\to D^{-1}R$ such that for all rings
> and morphisms $\psi\colon R\to S$ satisfying
>
> $\psi(D)\subset S^{\times}$
>
> there is a unique morphism $\Psi\colon D^{-1}R\to S$ such that
> $\Psi\circ\pi=\psi$.

**In the case we don't assume the condition $\psi(D)\subset S^{\times}$,**
what is the counterexample of the statement ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Any map where some element of $D$ maps to a nonunit will yield a counterexample. For instance, take $R=S=\mathbb{Z}$, $\psi=\mathrm{id}_{\mathbb{Z}}$, $D=\{a\in\mathbb{Z}\mid a\neq 0\}$. Then $D^{-1}R\cong\mathbb{Q}$, and there is no extension of the identity map $\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}$ to a ring morphism $\mathbb{Q}\to\mathbb{Z}$. By the way, the use of "the" in "what is the counterexample" is incorrect: there isn't a single distinguished "counterexample". It should be "What is **a** counterexample..."

Answer (score 2):

For any ring map, units map to units.

If you have a map $\psi\colon R\to S$ such that $\psi(D)$ is not mapped into the units of $S$, then you cannot possibly have a diagram $\psi = \Psi\circ\pi$, since $\pi(D)$ consists of units, and hence $\Psi(\pi(D))=\psi(D)$ must also consist of units.